# Is it correct to say "we sell car-repair services to customers"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-usage, phrase-choice

This is my guess. It sounds better if we use "**sell**" for "**tangible products**" and "**offer**" for "**services**".

For example, "*we sell cars/ washing machines*"

and "*we offer car-repair services to customers*"

It doesn't sound good to say "*we sell car-repair services to customers*". But [Google book](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22sell+car-repair+services+%22) has some hits about "**sell car-repair services**"

Comment: It isn't **incorrect** - we speak of 'selling insurance' - but you are right in saying that **sell** is more often used with reference to tangible things.

Answer (score 2):

Your intuition is right. We typically **sell** goods, whereas for services a more typical verb is ***provide***.

The respective connotations are not perfectly parallel though, since (1) goods too can be provided, and (2) *sell* definitely implies an exchange for money, while *provide* could include, say, a charitable donation.

*Offer* is like *provide* in that it can be used for either goods or services. Its special difference is that one can offer without anyone’s acceptance, in which case the goods or services are not, in the end, provided.

And, in any event, the prepositional phrase *to customers*, though not wrong, is redundant and essentially never used.